# cannot return Double Value in JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable, double, defaulttablemodel

I am making a ui in which i read data from a text file and save it to another text file after the user edits in it.i want to return integer values for all columns except column 6 and 7.For column 6 and 7 i want to return double values.Everything in this program works fine only for column 6 and column 7 when user edit in it until they enter a integer value it shows red marks in the cells whereas i should be double values for column 6 and column 7.please help

Code:

```
 import java.awt.*;
 import java.awt.event.*;
 import java.io.*;
 import java.util.*;
 import javax.swing.*;
 import javax.swing.table.*;

 public class Read extends JFrame
 {
 private JTable table;
 private DefaultTableModel model;

 @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
 public Read()
 {

      String aLine ;
      Vector columnNames = new Vector();
      Vector data = new Vector();

      try
      {
           FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream("test1.txt");
           BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fin));


           StringTokenizer st1 = new StringTokenizer(br.readLine(), " ");

           while( st1.hasMoreTokens() )
           {
                columnNames.addElement(st1.nextToken());
           }


           while ((aLine = br.readLine()) != null)
           {
                StringTokenizer st2 = new StringTokenizer(aLine, " ");
                Vector row = new Vector();

                while(st2.hasMoreTokens())
                {
                     row.addElement(st2.nextToken());
                }
                data.addElement( row );
           }
           br.close();
      }
      catch (Exception e)
      {
           e.printStackTrace();
      }

      final JTable table = new JTable(new DefaultTableModel(data, columnNames){
      private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

  @Override
  public Class getColumnClass(int column) {
       return Integer.class;
       }
  });


  JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane( table );
      getContentPane().add( scrollPane );


      JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel();
      getContentPane().add( buttonPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH );


      JButton button1 = new JButton( "Save" );
      buttonPanel.add( button1 );
      button1.addActionListener( new ActionListener()
      {
           public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
           {
               if  ( table.isEditing() )
                {
                     int row = table.getEditingRow();
                     int col = table.getEditingColumn();
                     table.getCellEditor(row, col).stopCellEditing();
                }

                int rows = table.getRowCount();
                int columns = table.getColumnCount();



     try { 
       StringBuilder con = new StringBuilder();
       for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
        {
          for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++)
           {
              Object Value = table.getValueAt (i, j);
              con.append(" ");
              con.append(Value);
           }
          con.append("\r\n");
        }

    FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter(new File("new.txt"));

    fileWriter.write(con.toString());
    fileWriter.flush();

   }  catch (Exception ex) {  
            ex.printStackTrace();  
        }  
    }
   });

  }

 public static void main(String[] args)
 {
      Read a = new Read();
      a.setDefaultCloseOperation( EXIT_ON_CLOSE );
      a.pack();
      a.setVisible(true);
 }
}
```

text file

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
78 12 12 45 4 0.0045 0.0078 45
45 45 69 56 7 0.0056 0.0023 21
45 89 76 42 1 0.0036 0.0023 36
```

Comment: How are you suppose to support doubles when `getColumnClass` returns only `Integer.class;`?

Comment: Also just an FYI, as stated in the [`StringTokenizer` API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html) - "`StringTokenizer` is a legacy class that is retained for compatibility reasons although its use is discouraged in new code. It is recommended that anyone seeking this functionality use the `split` method of `String`"

Comment: Also you may want to parse the value before adding them to the vector

Answer (score 4):

`TableModel#getColumnClass` is used to determine which renderer AND which editor should be used by the `JTable`.

When you use `Integer.class` for the column class, the `JTable` sets up a `JFormattedField` configured to only allow whole numbers to be accepted.  You need to modify the `getColumnClass` to return the correct data type of the given column, for example...

```
@Override
public Class getColumnClass(int column) {
    return column == 5 || column == 6 ? Double.class : Integer.class;
}
```

You should also make sure that the data you are entering into the model is capable of meeting this contract, for example...

```
while (st2.hasMoreTokens()) {
    Object num = null;
    String value = st2.nextToken();
    Number num = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance().parse(value);
    row.addElement(num);
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @MadProgrammer,can u please tell me if i change column 8 in my text file with values 5.33e-02.so i tried:
return column == 5 || column == 6 ? Double.class : column == 7 ? String.class : Integer.class;
and keeping the above code same as it is.I can edit in column 8 and put string values, but when
it reads from file the value 5.33e-02,it only displays 5.33 in table discarding the rest e-02.
Please Guide

Comment: When you have more the two class types to return, I would start using a switch statement or if statement as it will make it easier to manage. When the values are read from the file, they are parsed to double automatically...

Comment: How can  i return 5.33e-02 in column 5.